# Count how many directories have at least one file with specific extension

Tags: shell, files

How can I know how many directories (in current directory) have at least 1 file with a .mp3 extension.

No need recursion -- directory structure from current dir is for example:

```
1/blabla.mp3
2
3/something.mp3
4
5
```

The command should return that there are 2 dirs with mp3 file(s).

Comment: Is this homework?  :p

Comment: Can't this question be a legit one with purposes besides homework? :) I use this to know how many users on my website uploaded mp3's.

Comment: Yes, I was mostly kidding. The last line read to me like a school assignment :)

Comment: haha yeah, tried to word it as straight forward as I could :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
   yes | head -1 |
   find "$1/." ! -name . -prune -type f \
      \( -name '*.[mM][pP]3' -o -name '.*.[mM][pP]3' \) \
      -exec sh -c "read foo" \; -print
' {} {} \; | wc -l |
sh -c 'read n;echo "There are $n dirs with mp3 files."'
```

The outer "find" selects all the subdirs in the current dir. and then descends in each of these and finds non-recursively in them if they contain atleast 1 mp3 file including hidden and in a case insensitive manner.